# How to import projects and database from visual studio 2013 to website using publish profile

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-web-app-service

I started learning MVC 5 Asp.net a week now and I encountered a problem when I publish my project to azure.

I followed the tutorial here :http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/adding-validation

After that part I want to test on how to publish on web, but the time I publish it the database is inaccessible

http://sevenstate.azurewebsites.net/Movies

My question is how to fix this? Like import my local database to azure in a simple way or did i miss a step or two?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to import your database. VS takes care of that for you.

Build > Publish [Solution Name]

[image]